# JS: Calendar in the form of table is not showing because of error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' or Identifier Expected (Studio Code)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Unexpected token (, when trying to access a table through DOM. I'm trying to show the calendar if it is a certain month of the year, but JS it's identifying my table elements. There are two possible errors:

- Studio Code: Identifier expected. ts(1003)
- Browser console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

```js
 window.onload = getDate();
  function getDate() {
    let currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    let date7 = new Date(7); 
    let date8 = new Date(August, 2022);
    let date9 = new Date(September, 2022);
    let date10 = 10;
    let date11 = 11;
    let date12 = 12;
    if (currentMonth == date7) {
      document.getElementById.("july_22").style.display="table";
    }
    else if (currentMonth == date8) {
      document.getElementById.("august_22").style.display="table";
    }
    else if (currentMonth == date9) {
      document.getElementById.("september_22").style.display="table";
    }
    else if (currentMonth == date10) {
      document.getElementById.("october_22").style.display="table";
    }
    else if (currentMonth == date11) {
      document.getElementById.("november_22").style.display="table";
    }
    else if (currentMonth == date12) {
      document.getElementById.("december_22").style.display="table";
    }
    }
```

```html
 <table id="july_22" cols="4" rows="33" cellspacing="20px">
        <caption>July</caption>
        <thead>
            
            <tr>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thu</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
                <th>Sun</th>
            </tr>
        
       </thead>

       <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="day"></td>
            <td class="day"></td>
            <td class="day"></td>
            <td class="day"></td>
            <td class="day"></td>
            <td class="day">1</td>
            <td class="day">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day">3</td>
            <td class="day">4</td>
            <td class="day">5</td>
            <td class="day">6</td>
            <td class="day">7</td>
            <td class="day">8</td>
            <td class="day">9<br><p class="message">Fasting Day</p></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day">10</td>
            <td class="day">11</td>
            <td class="day">12</td>
            <td class="day">13<br><p class="message">Fasting Day</p></td> 
            <td class="day">14</td>
            <td class="day">15</td>
            <td class="day">16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day">17</td>
            <td class="day">18</td>
            <td class="day">19</td>
            <td class="day">20</td>
            <td class="day">21</td>
            <td class="day">22<br><p class="message">Ritual</p></td>
            <td class="day">23<br><p class="message">Fasting Day</p></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="day">24</td>
            <td class="day">25</td>
            <td class="day">26</td>
            <td class="day">27</td>
            <td class="day">28<br><p class="message">Fasting Day</p></td> 
            <td class="day">29</td>
            <td class="day">30</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
   
       
    </table>
```

Comment: `onload` should be a function reference, not the result of running the function. `document.getElementById.("july_22")` isn't valid JS; the argument is to `getElementById`; you have a spurious `.`

Comment: Yes, that was part of the problem too, thanks.

Comment: It's... the entire problem, plus a bonus problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu have a dot after `document.getElementById`. You need to remove it like
`document.getElementById("july_22").style.display = "table";`

Comment: Aaaah, the freaking period, I unconsciously typed it when the syntax doesn't need it, I need to pay attention to the details... Thank you!